# time series with panda group by column

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I'm trying to do a time series to obtain the number of trips, with the column date as index of the data frame.

My csv file looks like this:

```
date        trips
7/1/2013    16650
7/2/2013    22745
1/1/2014    6059
```

....

```
bikes['date'] = pd.to_datetime(bikes['date']) 

dates=bikes.set_index(pd.to_datetime(bikes['date']), inplace=True)
```

Once I have the index, How should I get the time series with the number of trips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and then select column `trips` or use [`squeeze`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.squeeze.html):

```
bikes['date'] = pd.to_datetime(bikes['date']) 
bikes.set_index('date', inplace=True)

print (bikes['trips'])
date
2013-07-01    16650
2013-07-02    22745
2014-01-01     6059
Name: trips, dtype: int64

print (bikes.squeeze())
date
2013-07-01    16650
2013-07-02    22745
2014-01-01     6059
Name: trips, dtype: int64
```

Comment: thanks,Do you know how to plot that timeseries with Seaborn?

Comment: Unfortunately not.